# How to insert data into two tables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, insert, foreign-keys

I want to know how to insert data into two different tables.

I have

**Orders** table, which has:

OrderID, info, Price, VAT, Customer_ID

and **Customer** table

CustomerID, Name, LastName

Now i want to enter new order, which would have primary key of 1.

How can i write SQL that would enter this order for specific person,..let's say a person who has id of 1 in customer table?

This is what i have so far, but i just can't find solution

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Orders] (info, Price, VAT, Customer_ID) VALUES (@info, @Price, @VAT, @Customer_ID)"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@info", input1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", input2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAT", input3.Text);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

**UPDATE**

i don't want to enter foreign key(id) via textbox, but get it from current logged in user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question it should be a simple matter of adding another parameter.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO [Orders] (info, Price, VAT, Customer_ID) VALUES (@info, @Price, @VAT, @Customer_ID)"))
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@info", input1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", input2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAT", input3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_ID", input4.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If you do not have the customer_ID as an input field and want to make it always create an order for customer "1" then do the following

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO [Orders] (info, Price, VAT, Customer_ID) VALUES (@info, @Price, @VAT, 1)"))
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@info", input1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", input2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAT", input3.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If instead you are wanting to do something a bit more dynamic with looking up which customer an order is for we will need more information about your data input first. You'd need to do a select query to find the customer_ID and then pass that in as a parameter or just sub-select within the insert query.

**EDIT:**

Here's code using the dynamic query as you mentioned in the comments

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO [Orders] (info, Price, VAT, Customer_ID) SELECT @info, @Price, @VAT, CustomerID FROM Customer WHERE Name = @Username)"))
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@info", input1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", input2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAT", input3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", SomeVariableWithUsername);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: i don't want to input foreign key...i want to read it from current logged in user

Comment: Ok, is there a field in the customer table that matches with the current logged in user? 
If so then you can do a subselect using that uniquely identifying information in the customer table to find the correct customerid.
In that case you query would be like 
`INSERT INTO [Orders] (info, Price, VAT, Customer_ID) SELECT @info, @Price, @VAT, FROM Customer WHERE Name = @UserName)`
Then just add @UserName as another parameter

Comment: no you can see my fields in my question. Customer_ID should be number 1....based on that, customer could get his order info

Comment: If there is nothing the customer table that directly relates to the username then you would have to make the user choose the customer before entering the order. Then you just pass in that customerid like the other parameters.

Comment: i think ill just get my user id on login form, transfer it with session and use it on query. probably not the best architecture, but atleast it works

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your parametry is missing?

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_ID", input4.Text);
```

Comment: i don't want to input foreign key...i want to read it from current logged in user